# GPS provider receiver crash on app "clear data"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The title says it all.  I have a registered broadcast receiver in the manifest to detect GPS provider changes.  When the user selects "clear data" in the app settings, the process crashes immediately afterwards (Null pointer exception in Broadcast Receiver's onReceive method).

here's the manifest code for the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.GpsLocationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Anybody know why the receiver would crash when the app's data is cleared and/or a way to prevent it?  And, more importantly, why the receiver would fire immediately upon the app's data being cleared?

Comment: clear data forcibly closes the app as far as I know. What do you mean by "crash" ?

Comment: Also, removing runtime permissions, which should happen on clear data on Android 6.0+, stops the app's process.

Comment: @vlatkozelka the onReceive method of the receiver get's an NPE when trying to reference an object that is understandably dead at this point in the process

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but in this instance, the onReceive method of the receiver is firing when the data is cleared

Comment: So? Your process can be terminated at any time, for any reason, having little or nothing to do with the user clearing your app's data. Your `GpsLocationReceiver` *has* to be able to cope with this, by not relying on some objects already being created in the process by some other code.

Comment: @commonsware you are correct.  I'm just curious why this would only happen when clearing app data.  It doesn't happen when revoking permissions.  Specially, why does the onReceive method fire immediate when the data is cleared?

Comment: "why does the onReceive method fire immediate when the data is cleared?" -- no clue, sorry.

Comment: Add logging to your `onReceive()` to log the `Intent` that you get. I'm assuming that the PROVIDERS_CHANGED `Intent` is broadcast when you clear data, but that is just an assumption. Add logging and you can see why it is triggered.